# Rails 3 Validations - Association Properties, RSpec, and Factory Girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot, autotest

I'm trying to write a validation class in rails 3 that will check for the presence of at least one associated object that has a particular property value.

In my scenario, an Account can have many Users.  The User model has a "Role" string field.  An account must have at least one User with a Role that equals "admin".

The following code is breaking during my testing (I'm using rspec & Factory Girl).  When the tests are executed, the account_id is returning as null.

Here is the model:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
  validate :has_one_admin
  has_many :users
  attr_accessible :name

  private 

  def has_one_admin
    User.where(:role => "admin", :account_id => self.id).count > 0
  end
end
```

Here is the error being thrown by rspec:

```
Error message being thrown:   Failure/Error: @account = Factory(:account_with_admin)
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.account_id: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" WHERE "users"."role" = 'admin' AND "users"."account_id" IS NULL
```

Here is the RSpec test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Team do

   # - Removed -  
   # before(:each) do
   #   @account = Factory(:account)
   #  @attr = { :name => "Testing Team"}
   # end

  # Modified after discussion...
  before(:each) do
    @user = Factory(:user)
    @act_attr = { :name => "My Account",
                  :users => @user }
    @account = Account.new(@act_attr)
    @attr = { :name => "Testing Team"}
  end
  # End of modification


  it "must have a name" do
    no_name_team = Team.new(@attr.merge(:name  => ""))
    no_name_team.should_not be_valid
  end ...
```

And finally, my factory file:

```
Factory.define :admin, :class => User do |f|
  f.email 'admin@admin.com'
  f.password  'password'
  f.role 'admin'
end

Factory.define :team, :class => Team do |f|
f.name 'Testing Team'   
end

Factory.define :account, :class => Account do |f|
    f.name 'Testing Account'
end

Factory.define :account_with_admin, :parent => :account do |f|
  f.after_create { |a| Factory(:admin, :account => a) }
end
```

My assumption is that I'm jumping ahead of the persisting of the object somewhere but I'm just not sure where.  Thanks for any help / direction!

Comment: According to the error message it is a problem with your database: the column `users.account_id` does not exists. You should have a look at your migrations and schema.rb.

Comment: I did check the schema / database first thing and can confirm that they are there.  If I comment out the validation, the code works fine so I don't think it's schema related.   Also, the rake db:migrate and rake db:test:clone commands were both executed prior to testing.

Comment: Very strange. I was just reacting to the error message that clearly states that the column does not exist. I don't understand your account_with_admin factory. You are calling `Factory(:admin, ...)`, which is defined nowhere. Small remark about your validation, I would rewrite it like this: `users.where(:role => "admin").count > 0`. Sorry I cannot help you further.

Comment: Sorry about the admin class; it is now added.  I tried to add just what would be needed to keep the page size in check.  The problem with your suggestion is that it does not scope to the account, which is the whole point of the validation.  The account_with_admin factory is a suggestion I found online creating the account > user association to be used in testing.

Comment: Thanks for adding the admin factory. In this scenario the validation will always fail. You are creating an account without an admin and then create an admin and add it to the account. It should be the other way around. Another question: you don't get the SQLite error when you run your code in development? Only in test?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I agree that the ordering of the persistence might be throwing this for a loop.  I restructured the code a bit to handle the associations directly in the spec files themselves (See Above).                                                                                                                          

The original challenge of validating child associations with property values remains.

Comment: The SQLite exception is pretty clear and it can only mean there's a problem on the database side. I know you said you checked the database, but are you sure you connected to the TEST database when you check? Have you tried "rails c test" to replicate the issue?

Comment: I realise that it is clear, but I can guarantee that this is NOT a database issue.   When I change the code to create the object in the new way indicated above, the sql issue goes away. I believe it has something to do with how factory girl handles associations.  Regardless, this is not the error I am concerned with; I'm looking for the best way to write a custom validator that checks a collection of child objects and returns as valid if one of those objects has a field value of "admin".